Can 'Find' Be Classified as a Perceptual Verb?
I am an English instructor from Korea. I understand that perceptual verbs in a five-element sentence structure can take a bare infinitive or a present participle as the object complement. Can "find" be included within the scope of perceptual verbs? If it can, what would be some examples? I am asking because I want to provide my students with accurate information.
In this context, find is understood to mean "to perceive or regard something as being a certain way."
Further Clarification:
As requested, here are additional examples of five-element sentence structures:

Verbs that take a noun as the object complement: call, name, make

Example: I named him Peter.

Verbs that take an adjective as the object complement: get, find, keep, make

Example: I found the test difficult.

Perceptual verbs (object complement can be a bare infinitive or a participle):

Example: I saw her dance / dancing.

Causative verbs (object complement is a bare infinitive, or a past participle if the object is passive):

Example: I had him do this homework.

Further Edit:
I deeply agree with the sentiment expressed by many of you that there can be no absolute rules in language. However, as an English instructor preparing students for exams, I am compelled to teach grammar rules. (In Korea, middle school English exams often test how the complement of a verb changes depending on the verb in five-element sentence structures. For example, name is taught as a verb that takes a noun as its object complement.)
The reason I initially posted this question is that I have been teaching find as a verb that takes an adjective as its object complement in five-element structures.
However, one of my students shared that their school teacher stated that find is included in the category of perceptual verbs.
I wanted to verify whether I might have been teaching this incorrectly, and if so, make the necessary corrections. That is why I am seeking your opinions. I, too, wonder why find could be considered a perceptual verb.

It seems to me that the category "perceptual verbs" or "verbs of perception" draws its borders around a concept rather than a function; it's not mainly about grammatical mechanics but about semantic notion: Ways to talk about our senses. By that token, maybe "find can be a 'perceptual verb' if used to talk about physical sense," like "I entered the darkened room and found the light switch with my hand."

Thank you so much for your detailed and thoughtful explanation! I found your perspective on how 'find' can be considered a perceptual verb depending on the context very intriguing. Connecting it to sensory experiences brings a fresh angle to the discussion. Personally, it makes me wonder how the traditional definition of perceptual verbs and this expanded interpretation could coexist or complement each other. I really appreciate your insights—thanks again!

Hm, maybe you should edit to mention what "perceptual verbs" means to you; I was unfamiliar with the phrase and that's the impression I got from a few minutes of research. I find the phrase "verbs of perception" used more often than "perceptual verbs," but the latter is used in this paper that seems to have a lot to say on the topic.

I think "verbs of perception" or "perceptual verbs" is something that language learners are taught, but native speakers don't need to be told how to use what are very common verbs. "Find" is definitely more likely to take an adjective ("I found him repulsive") or an -ing form ("I found him sitting in the dark") as an object complement than a bare infinitive, while perceptual verbs wouldn't usually take an adjective.

You should also clarify whether the question is about the literal sense of "find" ("I was looking for my keys and found them in the kitchen") or more figurative senses ("I find it difficult to drive at night").

I feel that somewhere out there there's a 'rule' that 'all "perceptual verbs" may take a bare infinitive or a present participle as their object complement', as with 'I heard/saw him leave/leaving'.  As Andy says, this is worryingly close to 'defining' a category of verbs by both semantic and syntactic attributes. Almost always exceptions will be found in such enterprises. 'I smelled him arrive' is, I'd say, unacceptable to grossly facetious. 'The monitor detected him leave' is again very doubtful. The only inviolable rule in English is that there's no other inviolable rule in English.

You can look up 'perceptual verbs' by say searching for synonyms of 'observe';  some (semantically related) are notice / see / note / perceive / discern / remark / spot / detect / discover / distinguish /
realise / realise / recognise / comprehend / remember. It would be unwise to claim that all these comply with the bare infinitive or present participle 'rule'.

I don’t see how find could be a verb of perception. @AndyBonner — What’s the difference between I found the light switch with my hand and I found the light switch with my flashlight?

Since "find" can't be used with a bare infinitive, doesn't that automatically rule out its membership in the class of perceptual verbs as you've defined it?

Please edit the question to give the readers some examples of such five element sentence structures.

@AndyBonner The class of perception verbs in English are so-called because they share certain grammatical characteristics and happen to describe perceptions. However, they are a grammatical class. Not all verbs that describe perceptions are members of the famous class of perception verbs.

@Barmar To clarify, I am specifically referring to cases where find is interpreted as "to perceive or regard something as being a certain way" in the context of a five-element sentence structure.

@daisykoo Everyone seems to assume that, but the question should state it clearly. That's why I said to edit the question, not answer in a comment.

@Barmar Thank you for your suggestion. I’ve updated the question to clarify the meaning of find based on your feedback.

Gisbourne {1996} argues for the non-inclusion of watch, perceive, observe, notice, glimpse, and spot in the set of 'perception verbs', and I'd assume by analogy, other perception-associated verbs such as realise, find, discern, recall, comprehend, twig, grasp, remember ....

The class of perception verbs in English are generally so-called because they share certain grammatical characteristics and happen to describe perceptions. However, they constitute a grammatical class, not a semantic one. Not all verbs that semantically describe perceptions are members of the famous grammatical class of perception verbs. Is find a member of this class? Does it have the same kind of grammar as verbs such as see, watch, hear, feel, smell or observe?
No, the verb find does not pattern like a perception verb. Consider:

She heard her lover leave the building.
Can you watch them operate?
I felt it move.
She smelled it burn.

The plain forms of the verbs above are all perfectly grammatical after the perception verbs hear, watch feel and smell. However the following sentence with find is ungrammatical:

I found him juggle the bottles.

It looks as though find is not a perception verb in English.

You should probably distinguish between the class of perception verbs (within certain structures) and perception verbs in general (such as perceive, not licensing one or both structures), as you did in your comment, if I understand it correctly, at the end of >600 words (??) not all will read.

Yes; there needs to be a stipulative definition of 'perception verbs' here making it clear that this is a syntactic rather than a semantic classification, and showing some verbs that, while definitely verbs that describe perceptions, fail to qualify for this set. Note the dictionary definition Joshua gives: 'Perceptual verbs, also known as sensory verbs, are verbs that describe the process of perceiving or experiencing something through the senses (e.g., see, hear, feel, taste, smell).'

The normal everyday examples "leave the building", "watch them operate", "felt it move", "smelled it burn”, all make grammatical and semantic sense. But "found him juggle the bottles" is bizarre to say the least, so of course we'd find (!) it odd.  What about this example: "I found him waiting outside". Why is it different from "I saw him waiting outside”

@Mari-Lou A It seems strange that 'perception verbs' are defined (a stipulative definition) by some by their ability to undergo complex catenation involving both an infinitive or ing-form. Causative verbs take an infinitive, as in 'I made/let him stay' (or more typically, a to-infinitive, 'I forced/allowed him to attend'). We need an answer with reputable references.

I found him praying. I felt it moving.
She smelled it burning. I found him juggling the bottles. He found it burning.

@Mari-LouA, Edwin, Lambie Despite OP's wording, there's nothing unusual about taking an -ing form. There's hundreds of verbs that do that, as all of you know: I like watching the birds eating the worms, or I want Lambie doing the BBQ, or She hates Edwin fussing over the underpants or This involved Mari-Lou repainting the Cistine Chapel ceiling. The perception verbs are famous because outside of the modal verbs and the holy quadrinity  of help, let, make, have only the perception verbs take plain forms of the verb/ bare infinitives. Therein lies the lesson, as it were.

@Mari-LouA, Edwin, Lambie - Although there's loads of other interesting complementation patterns they have too, of course.

You might like to address the meaning of "find" in "I found the wine tasteless."

Below the belt.

'I bade him go ....' is grammatical. // '...observe him go ...' is perhaps borderline. //  'I noticed him go ...' is fine, though Gisbourne finds another reason to exclude this verb.

We don't normally say, "She was hearing her lover leave…” as opposed to "She was listening to the news”; "She was smelling it burn” as opposed to "They could smell smoke“, and "The dish tastes amazing” as opposed to "The meal is tasting delicious” but I feel that "I was feeling it move” is acceptable.  Isn't one of the differences between verbs of the senses (i.e. ‘perceptual’) and main verbs is the former expresses an involuntary action? "I found him waiting outside" suggests the action occurred without the speaker's volition similar to "Jason saw/found Marla with another man”

I did find found (when meaning little more than saw) with -ing forms, often; e.g., I found him crying on the porch. But not with a bare infinitive. 'I found him *cry there.' I can't think of an example that would work in that case.

Unhelpfully, Grammaring has 'After verbs of perception (see, watch, hear, listen, feel, smell, notice, observe etc.), the infinitive expresses a completed action:' A stipulative definition from a respected source is essential.
